# Excel: Trailing 3 month decline using data from a pivot table

Tags: excel-formula, pivot-table

(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5283466/calculate-moving-average-in-excel seems to be somewhat related. I'm curious to know the non-vba way to do this.)

My my pivot table has source data that creates a count of how many sales a person had in the past 36 days. Each day os 1 column in the pivot table, and the persons name is on the row.

Some of these people did not have sales on day1, day2, etc, and may only have 3 days where they sold something on days 14,15 and 16. No matter what their sequence, I want to to find the most recent sale data (closest to the right edge of pivot table) and calculate three sales increases e.g. C20/C19 will be >1 if they had more sales on the whatever day C20 is. The increase ca nbe fond by subtracting 1 and changing to percent. The problem is, if a person only had sales on d10, d11, d12 then how can I put a **general** formula in Excel to say "look for the most recent consecutive sales, then calculate this ratio"? For a person who had sales in the past three days, that's easy. It will be chaotic to hardcode where to look for each sales value.

```
     d1   d2   d3   d4...d7   d8   d9...d34  d35  d36   mostrecentincrease nextrecent
ant   1    5    7                                       7/5=1.4            5/1=5
bat                   ...10   11   12...                12/11=1.blah       11/10=1.1
cat   2    6    9   13
dog                                           19   20   20/19=1.blah       19/blank=0
elf   4                                                 4/dnexist=0
```

Comment: `dog` does not have 3 consecutive sales, do you want to compute the most recent increase based on last 2 consecutive sales? what if `ant` had a new sale on `d36`, but not in between, do you want to compute `d36/d3` ?

Answer (score 0):

i don't have excel here, but i hope this will guide you to the correct result (use `,` instead of `;` if that is your list separator):

1. define **sales** as a range of values from d1 to d36 for a given row (or use actual ranges)
2. compute positions of the last values for each row using these [array formulas](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/introducing-array-formulas-in-excel-HA001087290.aspx) (use ctrl+shift+enter instead of just enter after you write these formulas):

   **position_1** `=max(if(sales<>0;column(sales)))`

   **position_2** `=max(if((sales<>0)*(column(sales)<>position_1);column(sales)))`

   **position_3** `=max(if((sales<>0)*(column(sales)<>position_1)*(column(sales)<>position_2);column(sales)))`
3. retrieve the values:

   **value_1** `=index(sales;position_1)`
4. do some error handling (`=iferror(...;0)`) and the like...